# In Bayesian Statistics, can the data be a random variable drawn from the posterior of a separate model? Will the uncertainty flow through?

Tags: r, bayesian, dataset, posterior, hierarchical-bayesian

In the traditional Bayesian hierarchical approach, you typically have a hierarchy built on your coefficients.  That is to say, you might have your coefficient of interest distributed around some unknown mean and variance, and that mean is itself produced by some other process. So maybe the counts of salmon observed in a stream are a function of a variety of factors, including which stream we are examining.  The effect of stream on salmon counts are randomly distributed around a mean and variance, but each stream has its own mean, which is generated from some other random process that has to be generated.

But suppose you had a situation where instead of a parameter of the coefficients being randomly generated, instead your data are themselves unknown and drawn from a posterior of a different process. In effect, instead of B_0 + B_1 * X_1 + B_2 * X_2 where one of the parameters of B_1 has to be sampled from some other posterior, your X_1 is a sample as well.

So, for example, the number of votes a candidate receives can be calculated as the number of votes cast by white voters * the percent of votes cast by white voters for the candidate, plus the number of votes cast by persons of color * the percent of votes cast by persons of color in the election.  We are often interested in trying to estimate those two percentages, so call them your Beta_1 and Beta_2. So taking a dataset of votes cast by whites and persons of color in each precinct, we could easily estimate the percentages.

But in most countries we don't really know know the number of votes cast by whites and persons of color. So we have another estimate where the total number of votes cast in a precinct is estimated off of census data of white and persons of color populations in those precincts, which can then be used to generate posterior draws of white and POC votes cast in each precinct.

Can one properly do this? Does the uncertainty from the "turnout" model flow through properly to the "vote share" model? What might it even look like in something like JAGS?  I can't think of a reason you couldn't do this, but for some reason I have trouble wrapping my mind around this.

Thank you!

Comment: How would you construct your equation operationally? Instead of parameters and data, think in terms of unobservables and observables. Unobservables get a prior, observables do not. If you have a missing piece of data in a set, it is unobservable and can be treated as if a parameter. Likewise, if you know the variance is 3, that is observed and no longer gets a prior distribution as it is known. It seems you know precinct data and do not know specific votes. Given what you can observe, how would you operationalize your model?

Comment: So instead of:

y[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i], tau) 
mu[i] <- alpha + B_1 * x[i]

where B_1 is given, say, a normal prior with mean 0 and variance 1 and the xs are observed data, we'd have something like this: 

mu[i] <- alpha + B_1 * x_1[i]
x_1[i] <- delta + B_2 * z_1[i]

where z is our observed data.  That's the basic idea of what I'm thinking although I may not have written down correctly what should get an [i] and what shouldn't.